# Read text file on server into array javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's the situation. On the apache box there's a text file that contains numbers with new lines:
eg:

```
25
34
76
```

etc....

What I'm wanting to do it grab the values from that file and use them to "set" some sliders I have which are partially yoinked from http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/slider/slider.html

Once done I'll have a "commit" button which writes out the altered values to that text file.

But I'm getting stuck at the bit where you read from the text file on the apache box which this runs in.
Everything I've read seems to refer to file uploading via an API but this isn't what i want as the file is server side.

I guess I could use php but as I'm not up on that either (and especially not on how to move variables between the two)

Any ideas? If you need clarification i can give it to you.

Comment: look for "AJAX" - just ignore the "XML" bit.

Comment: You will obviously have to use some server scripting in order to save your changes afterwards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple ajax code!!!

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("mytextfiledic").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","mytextfile.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XMLHttpRequest` :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'GET', 'foobar.txt', true );
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {

        if( xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status<300 || xhr.status == 304  ) {
            //your text file is downloaded into xhr.responseText
            console.log( xhr.responseText.split('\n') );// there you have your array.
        }

    }

}
xhr.send();
```